# Django with Tastypie: How to store followers,followers_count in the Profile?

Tags: django, tastypie

I have:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=140)  
    profile_picture = models.URLField()

class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="who_follows")
    followed = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="who_is_followed")
    follow_time = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

So what should be ProfileResource in order that I can get followers_count? Or can I POST that user has a new follower?

My ProfileResource is:

```
class ProfileResource(ModelResource):
    followers_count = Follow.objects.filter(followed=)
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'profile'
        filtering = {
            'username': ALL,
        }
```

Is it the best way? Or I should use it like:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=140)  
    profile_picture = models.URLField()
    followers = ToManyField('self')
    following = ToManyField('self')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get a count of followers via a attribute. Try something like:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    def followers_count(self):
        return self.user.who_is_followed.all().count()

class ProfileResource(ModelResource):
    followers_count = fields.CharField(attribute='followers_count')
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I need to get user's followers list?

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner if the follower's list is a seperate resource?

Comment: If you want a actual list of objects you would need to related resources - see http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#reverse-relationships

Comment: Which way is the best? ToManyField in Profile or keeping relations in Follow modal?

Comment: I would also add `readonly=True` to followers_count tastypie fields, so it wouldn't try to update in the model while put requests to update profile model

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to annotate the follower's count in the queryset, so that you can do it in one database call:

```
queryset = User.objects.annotate(number_of_followers=Count('follow'))
```